# Windows 7 Pro dell 750 Computer parallel port FX-80 Driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printer

I have a special needs son. I want to install an Epson FX-80 printer on the parallel port and I can’t find a printer driver for windows 7.  I am very knowledgeable about computers.
Because it is so slow it causes him to use less paper. He may only type 20 words on a page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I was happy with XP pro.

Comment: 32 or 64-bit Windows 7?  How/where did you try to find drivers for it?

Comment: To broaden the scope of your question a bit: If i understand you correctly, the point is to slow down printing for your son so he does not go through a pallet of paper in a week? My thinking is: There might be other approaches that might help people in similar situations. Another thought comes to mind with dot matrix printers: Consider providing him with ear protection if you haven't already. ;-)

Comment: Ha Ha I also like the fact I can hear him printing anywhere in the house. He love having a printer and I would never use it for anything else. I have 1.5 cases of paper and two ribbons and Staples stills sales the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone was interested, I was able to make Epson FX-80 work in Windows 7 64-bit. But I didn't use any Epson driver, I used "Generic IBM Graphics 9-pin" that can be found in the standard Windows printer list.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Epson](http://esupport.epson-europe.com/ViewArticle.aspx?lng=en-GB&kbid=324521) the drivers are included with Windows.

This is half true -- they are available from MS via Windows Update.

Use the Add Printer wizard to add the printer manually, and when you get to the part about choosing the driver, hit the "Windows Update" button to have it go get more drivers.

This will take a while.

Once it's loaded, look under Epson for a printer driver named "EPSON FX Series 1 (136)".

Comment: As per the linked page, the printer driver package is meant to be called **FX Series 1 (80)**. Both the 80 and 136 variants are actually included in the same package, so it doesn't really matter in this case. The driver is included with Windows 7, and can be found in the `System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prnep004.inf_xxx` folder. The version available through Windows Update is newer, however. To save time you can download the package straight from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Rss.aspx?q=epson+fx+series+80).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, our local go to guy wanted over $200 to do it and would not tell me how. I am just learning my way around Windows 7, I am an XP expert and I guess it is time to move.